# How Do I See What Programs are Using My RAM?

Tags: memory

At the most ridiculous of times during the day, my RAM usage will suddenly spike from 30% to 99% and freeze my PC.  Malware programs see nothing, and no sign of hardware issues.  I want to know what's stealing all of my resources to cause this.

Note: I am not getting any errors, no corrupt files, no blue screen, no kernel errors, no BIOS warnings.  It just freezes, stops, then I reset PC, and everything is fine again (until it repeats at some random time).

Comment: We need more information other then this happens.  We need to know what processes are running when this happen.

Comment: Also, OS version would be useful. **EDIT**: pardon, I did notice the phrase "blue screen". So it must be windows. The question still stands, what version are you running?

Comment: Is there any consistency in what you are doing at the time? Doing the same task, running the same programs etc. I assume you aren't looking for an answer as simple as "Open Task Manager > Click Processes" to view your Memory usage.

Comment: If you're using Windows 8, open Task Manager and look at the Processes tab.

Comment: Have you run any hardware diagnostics? Manufacturers usually have some sort of tool you can use. Of course, when more information is given, someone can give you more specific help. [MemTest86+](http://www.memtest.org/#downiso) might be a good idea to ensure your RAM is OK.

Answer (score 0):

[RAMMap](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/08/13/introduction-to-the-new-sysinternals-tool-rammap.aspx) is **the** tool to see the memory usage in Windows. My link points to a Microsoft Blog post which explains what the values mean.

Comment: RAMmap is an extremely useful tool, but he says his machine is freezing when the problem happens. So he's not going to be able to run RAMmap or even click its Refresh button at that time.